# Solve matrix equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I have an equation of the type `c = Ax + By` where `c`, `x` and `y` are vectors of dimensions say 50,000 X 1, and `A` and `B` are matrices with dimensions 50,000 X 50,000.

Is there any way in Matlab to find matrices `A` and `B` when `c`, `x` and `y` are known?

I have about 100,000 samples of `c`, `x`, and `y`. `A` and `B` remain the same for all.

Comment: Is that possible mathematically? Unless I'm being stupid, it sounds like you have more unknowns than equations...

Comment: Dan: it's 2 unknowns, 100 000 equations. I guess that should do :) .

Comment: It looks to me like 5 million unknows? Each element of Matrix A and B?

Comment: @Dan - please see my answer for an estimate of number of unknowns and equations. If you agree with my estimate - can you please remove your comments?

Comment: If A and B are both matrices, and are both unknown, then it certainly is 5 BILLION unknowns (5e9). The problem is unsolvable, at least if you want a unique answer.

Comment: @Wli - No. It is NOT 2 unknowns. It is 2 unknown MATRICES, each of size 50000x50000, thus 5e9 unknowns.

Comment: @Shai My matrix algebra isn't stellar but I'm afraid I don't agree with your explanation. Perhaps you could include a demonstration where A and B are 2x2 instead of 50000x50000? I admit I mistype billion as million but I don't see why my comments should be removed, I feel they are quite valid questions even if you are right.

Comment: You need to add some constraint. Ask for some norm to be minimum and you will have a solution.

Comment: @woodchips I should go back to school :( . Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Dan - I updated my answer - I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `X` be the collection of all 100,000 `x`s you got (such that the `i`-th column of `X` equals the `x_i`-th vector).
In the same manner we can define `Y` and `C` as 2D collections of `y`s and `c`s respectively.

What you wish to solve is for `A` and `B` such that

```
C = AX + BY
```

You have 2 * 50,000^2 unknowns (all entries of `A` and `B`) and `numel(C)` equations.

So, if the number of data vectors you have is 100,000 you have a single solution (up to linearly dependent samples). If you have more than 100,000 samples you may seek for a least-squares solution.

Re-writing:

```
C = [A B] * [X ; Y]  ==>  [X' Y'] * [A';B'] = C'
```

So, I suppose

```
[A' ; B'] = pinv( [X' Y'] ) * C'
```

In matlab:

```
ABt = pinv( [X' Y'] ) * C';
A = ABt(1:50000,:)';
B = ABt(50001:end,:)';
```

Correct me if I'm wrong...

**EDIT:**
It seems like there is quite a fuss around dimensionality here. So, I'll try and make it as clear as possible.

**Model:** There are two (unknown)  matrices `A` and `B`, each of size 50,000x50,000 (total 5e9 unknowns).
An observation is a triplet of *vectors*: (`x`,`y`,`c`) each such vector has 50,000 elements (total of 150,000 observed points at *each sample*).  The underlying model assumption is that an observation is generated by `c = Ax + By` in this model.
**The task:** given `n` observations (that is `n` triplets of *vectors* { (`x_i`, `y_i`, `c_i`) }_`i=1..n`) the task is to uncover `A` and `B`.

Now, each sample (`x_i`,`y_i`,`c_i`) induces 50,000 equations of the form `c_i = Ax_i + By_i` in the unknown `A` and `B`. **If** the number of samples `n` is **greater** than 100,000, then there are more than 50,000 * 100,000 ( > 5e9 ) equations and the system is **over constraint**.

To write the system in a matrix form I proposed to stack all observations into matrices:

- A matrix `X` of size 50,000 x `n` with its `i`-th column equals to observed `x_i`
- A matrix `Y` of size 50,000 x `n` with its `i`-th column equals to observed `y_i`
- A matrix `C` of size 50,000 x `n` with its `i`-th column equals to observed `c_i`

With these matrices we can write the model as:

C = A*X + B*Y

I hope this clears things up a bit.

Thank you @Dan and @woodchips for your interest and enlightening comments.

**EDIT (2):**
Submitting the following code to [octave](http://weboctave.mimuw.edu.pl/weboctave/web/index.php#menus). In this example instead of 50,000 dimension I work with only 2, instead of `n=100,000` observations I settled for `n=100`:

```
n = 100;
A = rand(2,2);
B = rand(2,2);
X = rand(2,n);
Y = rand(2,n);
C = A*X + B*Y + .001*randn(size(X)); % adding noise to observations 
ABt = pinv( [ X' Y'] ) * C';
```

Checking the difference between ground truth model (`A` and `B`) and recovered `ABt`:

```
ABt - [A' ; B']
```

Yields

```
  ans =

   5.8457e-05   3.0483e-04
   1.1023e-04   6.1842e-05
  -1.2277e-04  -3.2866e-04
  -3.1930e-05  -5.2149e-05
```

Which is close enough to zero. (remember, the observations were noisy and solution is a least-square one).

Comment: @woodchips: (1) please feel free to edit `pinv` line so the syntax is correct. (2) More importantly, if there are more than 100,000 triplets of `x`, `y` and `c` why should there be more than a single solution?

Comment: You have more unknowns than equations. It is a linear system, so the problem is underdetermined, so there are INFINITELY many solutions. I'll get back to fix your line later.

Comment: @woodchips - you have unknowns 2*50,000^2 = 5E9 unknowns (number of elements in `A` and `B`). You have `numel(C)` equations = 50,000 (dim) x ~100,000 (number of samples) = 5E9. **IF** number of samples is **greater** than 100,000 than you have more equations than unknowns! this is an **over**determined system and does not have infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @woodchips - it seems like this subject is very touchy for you. Your comments are quite aggressive. (1) I double-checked `pinv` syntax in Matlab and I still believe my code is correct. (2) as I already pointed in my answer if there are more than 100,000 samples (each sample is a 50,000-vector) than the system is overdetermined. please review your comments and feel free to delete those that are misleading.

Comment: pinv returns a SIMPLE array. Multiply that by another array, and it is an array. You CANNOT stuff an array into a form like [A';B']. This is illegal syntax that fails in MATLAB.

Comment: Can't try it in Matlab right now so I ran it in Octave online (http://weboctave.mimuw.edu.pl/weboctave/web/index.php#menus) so it may be slightly different to matlab. I ran it with 4 equations instead of 100000, so we expect your last line (i.e. the only line of code we need to run right?) to return a 4 by 2 matrix right? X = [1, 2, 1, 2];
Y = [1, 0.5, 1.1, 0.6];
C = [7, 4, 5, 2,];

pinv( [X' Y'] ) * C'; This return just a 2 element matrix [ 0.017508; 5.540680]; Have I misunderstood the dimensions in your solution?

Comment: Oh ok I think I see what you're saying, are you saying the dimensions of your X, Y and C are 50000x100000? Then I agree that it is possible. My understanding of the data available was different. On a side note though, the following code actaully cause Matlab to crash on my side: >> X = [1, 2, 1, 2];
Y = [1, 0.5, 1.1, 0.6];
C = [7, 4, 5, 2,];
[A' ; B'] = pinv( [X' Y'] ) * C' I wonder if anyone else's installation has the same behaviour?

Comment: Am sorry for the delay, got stuck in other work, but does not seem to work for me  "operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2000x1, op2 is 1000x1)", Tried on 1000 dimensions instead of 50000, did i miss something??

Comment: @user1521554 - check the dimensions in the example.