# How to find the coefficients of a linear combination matrix using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, vector

I was wondering what the code on Matlab would look like in order to find `c1` and `c2` of the linear combination `c1*x+c2*y=z`.

Note: The matrix `A` will have size 3*`n`, and the first row of `A` is the vector `x`, the second row is the vector `y`, and the third row is the vector `z`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solve matrix equation in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502145/solve-matrix-equation-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1):

```
C = A(1:2, :)'\A(3, :)';
```

C is the vector of [c1 c2].

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Would it be possible to write the code using linsolve?

Comment: C = linsolve(A(1:2, :)', A(3, :)');
you can use 'help linsolve' in matlab's command window to see its detail usage.

Comment: I get this error when I do so:     3
    error: 'v' undefined near line 15 column 1
    error: called from
    mp1 at line 15 column 1  What can I do to remove the error?